# Is it possible to classify RTD pages using tags (sort of taxonomy)?

Tags: read-the-docs

I would like to add for every page a sort of classification using comma separated tags (i.e. javascript, REST, HTML5).

And I would like to have a way to use one of this tag, to open the list of the pages classified using this tag.

Is it possible?